# Copy Contents of Outlook Attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook VBA macro that copies the contents of an email and saves them as a word document, using

```
activeMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
```

I'd like to change this to copy the contents of the email attachments instead.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to save the attachment as a file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), open it (depends on the file type), then access its data.