# Copy content of Excel attachment in Outlook VBA without saving the file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get 50 mails with Excel sheets per day. I want to add the first line of each Excel sheet to an existing Excel sheet located on my computer.

I know how to save a file from an email, and then access the first line. I would like to directly access it, without having to save the file.

Something like this:

```vb
Sub Merge_Reports(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim wb_path As String
Dim app_master As Object
Dim wb_master As Object
Dim ws_master As Object
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim ws_email As Object
Dim content As String

wb_path = "\\swi56prof01\UserData$\heinreca\Documents\Outlook-Dateien\AllData.xlsx"
Set app_master = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb_master = app_master.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
Set ws_master = wb_master.Sheets(1)

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
  Set ws_email = objAtt.Sheets(1)
  content = ws_email.Cells("A1")
  ws_master.Cells("A1") = content
End Sub
```

I am struggling with `ws_email = objAtt.Sheets(1)`. I get the error

> object doesn't support this property or method

I tried this instead of the line that results in the error.

```vb
Set app_email = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb_email = app_email.Workbooks.Open(objAtt)
Set ws_email = wb_email.Sheets(1)
```

I don't know what `objAtt` is in terms of data type and how to address the worksheet, so that I can copy the first line from it.

I found [Copy Contents of Outlook Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210648/copy-contents-of-outlook-attachment) and that I have to save the file before accessing it. Is there no other way?

Comment: I think you can't access without saving it, because to open it it needs to be extracted of the email (as emails encode files in a special way they need to be decoded first). Then the file needs to be opened to be able to read the data. So even if you double click the Excel file in Outlook it will temporarily save that file in the temp folder to be able to open and show it. • I see no way to get around the following procedure steps: saving to disk, opening, reading, closing, deleting.

Comment: Okay I see, then I'll do it like that - thanks!

Comment: Now that you have an answer to this "non-answerable" question you cannot change it. You might get a solution if you post a new question describing the specific aspect of the process that is not acceptable. Possibly it is about Excel flashing open 50 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the workbook without saving it to the disk. After saving the attached file to the disk you can use the same code:

```
Set wb_master = app_master.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
Set ws_master = wb_master.Sheets(1)
```

where `wb_path` is the file path of your saved attachment (Excel file).

The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method saves the attachment to the specified path. For example:

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then 
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then 
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem 
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
     'Prompt the user for confirmation 
     Dim strPrompt As String 
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
       myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _ 
       myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName 
     End If 
   Else 
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type." 
   End If 
 End If 
End Sub
```